# deleting columns marked as primary key mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```sql
CREATE TABLE tipo_centro (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    descripcion VARCHAR(150),
    naturaleza integer NOT NULL,
    comunidad integer NOT NULL,
    provincia integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, naturaleza, comunidad, provincia),
    FOREIGN KEY (naturaleza) REFERENCES naturaleza (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (comunidad) REFERENCES comunidad (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (provincia) REFERENCES provincia (id)
) ENGINE innodb;
```

with, just a sample, this data:

```
id      descripcion                         naturaleza  comunidad   provincia
1   Centro de Enseñanzas de Régimen General     0           0       0
1   Centro de Enseñanzas de Régimen General     0           6       39
1   Centro de Enseñanzas de Régimen General     1           0       0
1   Centro de Enseñanzas de Régimen General     1           6       39
```

I want to delete `naturaleza`, `comunidad`, `provincia` columns and just have one different value for pair {id,descripcion}, so first I need to drop the primary key:

```
alter table tipo_centro drop primary key;
```

but it fails with error code 1025

anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: Error 1025 can point to the fact that primary key you are dropping is actually referenced as foreign key in some other table in the database. Can this be the case for you?

Comment: of course, havent you seen the create table structure???

Answer (score 0):

One Line:

ALTER TABLE  `tipo_centro` DROP PRIMARY KEY , ADD PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )

if id is the only primary u want

Comment: I have already tried that, ERROR: duplicate entry '1' for primary.

Comment: yes u have to drop the data first bcoz if u dont drop data then after making id primary it is still having duplicate values so use this command "DELETE * FROM table_name;"

Answer (score 0):

Try this statement, because it is a composite primary key you have to drop the constraint on the table first, then add the column to your primary key. Try it out and see :))

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tipo_centro
DROP CONSTRAINT tipo_centro_PK
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I have created a new table tipo_centro_lite with just the 2 columns I need.
anyway, thanks everybody!!